Proving $\forall w\,,x,\,y,\,z: \,(((wx)y)z)=(w(x(yz)))$ in natural deduction from $\forall x,\, y,\, z:\, ((xy)z) = (x(yz))$
I am currently failing to do an exercise on natural deduction in first order logic, and I am failing quite hard. The exercise is to formally prove $\forall w\,,x,\,y,\,z: \ (((wx)y)z)=(w(x(yz)))$ from the premise $\forall x,\, y,\, z: ((xy)z) = (x(yz))$ in two different ways. I am struggling to even manage it once.
I can see that informally $((wx)y)z = (w(xy))z = w((xy)z) = w(x(yz))$ or $((wx)y)z = (wx)(yz) = w(x(yz))$. So I guess I should do $\forall$-elimination, somehow do the above and then $\forall$-introduction. The issue is then how I would formalize the above into natural deduction. I believe some substitutions are required, but that isn't really my strong side and I think I need to see how to do it first. Or if there's another trick I am supposed to do?
Thanks in advance for the help!

What rule do you have that allows you to do substitution?  (For example, one possibility is a rule "${=}E$" which says: if you have a formula $\varphi$ with free variable $a$, and then you have $\Gamma \vdash x = y$ and $\Gamma \vdash \varphi[a/x]$, then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi[a/y]$.  So then for example, in your context you can apply the premise to get $(wx)y = w(xy)$, and also by "${=}I$" or "reflexivity of equality" you have $((wx)y)z = ((wx)y)z$.  Therefore, applying ${=}E$ with $\varphi := [((wx)y)z = a z]$ you conclude what?

(Of course, you probably need restrictions such as $a$ not appearing in $\Gamma$ or in the terms $x$ or $y$.)

I guess that also brings up the question: is your natural deduction system more on the tree-based approach, or is it more on the Fitch approach of writing out a sequence of lines with some indentation?

@DanielSchepler I have $=E$ and following you I conclude $(w(xy))z$, which I recognize as a first step towards the "end goal". After thinking about it for a while now, I believe I can do the rest of the proof by myself. Thank you for leading me right!

In this course we use the tree-based approach. Also the restrictions you mentioned seem like they aren't an issue here, as far as I can tell.
